# use powershell to load new IE windows and do things in background

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, powershell

I am using the following home-made script to extract data from an in-house database with an web-interface restricted to IE only.

```
function script([string]$cluster, [string]$fromdate, [string]$todate)
{
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://testing.home")
Start-Sleep -s 5
$ie.visible=$true
$doc=$ie.document
$login1 = $doc.getElementByID("TxtUser")
$login2 = $doc.getElementByID("TxtPassword")
$loginbtn = $doc.getElementByID("BtnLogin")
$login1.value= "username"
$login2.value= "password"
$loginbtn.click()
Start-Sleep -s 5
$ie.navigate("http://testing.home/download.aspx")
Start-Sleep -s 5
$dl1 = $doc.getElementById("ddlloc")
$dl2 = $doc.getElementById("txtFromDate")
$dl3 = $doc.getElementById("txtToDate")
$dl1.value=$cluster
$dl2.value=$fromdate
$dl3.value=$todate
$dlbtn = $doc.getElementByID("btnSearch")
$dlbtn.click()

Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

It works OK for me, but I wonder if the script can be modified so that everything is done in background, without interrupting my work in my active window.

I am using Win7. I wonder if there is any simple way for fixing it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a background job?

Comment: @Andy nope, but I build the script mostly by copy-n-paste, can you enlighten me a bit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to set:

```
$ie.visible=$false
```

On a side note I would advise you to not use IE at all and write several HttpWebRequest calls, it will give you some more reliability and will not require running IE (that consumes memory and cpu)

Comment: Marking you up for $ie.visible=$false - however the only reason we are all seeing IE and COM as a solution is that it is the best tool for scraping html. Downloading option as you suggest has just wasted me 2 days to get working because html is very hard to scrape generically, and yes, I have tried a few tools which, at the end of the day leaves one with the time trade-off vs some virtual memory IE may waste, which is really free these days.

Comment: IE still runs via com, the visible flag only toggles visibility of the window... I'd agree though that using straight HTTP requests is more reliable and efficient way, but most applications these days require executing javascipt, etc, where the full blown browser is needed to do the trick.